# Rotate BufferedImage with transparent background

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have an image with transparent background. I'd like to rotate this image to a specific angle and keep the transparent background for the resulting image. For this purpose I use the following method:

```
public static BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage image, double angle, Color backgroundColor) {
    System.out.println(image.getType());
    double theta = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(theta));
    double cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(theta));
    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();
    int newW = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);
    int newH = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

    BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, image.getType());
    Graphics2D g2d = tmp.createGraphics();
    if (backgroundColor != null) {
        g2d.setColor(backgroundColor);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, newW, newH);
    } 
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, newW, newH);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    g2d.translate((newW - w) / 2, (newH - h) / 2);
    g2d.rotate(theta, w / 2, h / 2);
    g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.dispose();
    return tmp;
}
```

I invoke it with background=null:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
rotateImage(image, 4, null);
ImageIO.write(bi, "PNG", new File("image.png"));
```

but the background of the resulting image.png is WHITE. What am I doing wrong and how to properly keep the transparent background for image.png?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled about the behavior of `Graphics.drawImage()`. Maybe somebody else can comment about it.

However, `Graphics2D.drawRenderedImage()` works a treat. It takes an `AffineTransform` to control the rotation. The below example nicely works. You probably have additional requirement about the final image size and the location of the rotated image.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

public class ImageRotation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageRotation rotation = new ImageRotation();
        rotation.rotate("input.png", 45, "output.png");
    }

    public void rotate(String inputImageFilename, double angle, String outputImageFilename) {

        try {
            BufferedImage inputImage = ImageIO.read(new File(inputImageFilename));
            BufferedImage outputImage = rotateImage(inputImage, angle);
            ImageIO.write(outputImage, "PNG", new File(outputImageFilename));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage sourceImage, double angle) {
        int width = sourceImage.getWidth();
        int height = sourceImage.getHeight();
        BufferedImage destImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = destImage.createGraphics();

        AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
        transform.rotate(angle / 180 * Math.PI, width / 2 , height / 2);
        g2d.drawRenderedImage(sourceImage, transform);

        g2d.dispose();
        return destImage;
    }
}
```

**Update**

While the above code works for most PNGs, it does not work for the [image](http://download.decisionwanted.com/image2_cleared_1-2149x1417+1443+479.png) that alexanoid is using. I've analyzed the image:

- It's a grayscale image without a color palette (PNG color type 0) .
- It uses simple transparency with a 2 byte long tRNS chunk.

As far as I can tell that's perfectly legal. However, ImageIO does not implement this combination. If the image has no palette, it simply ignores the tRNS chunk and therefore ignores the transparency information. That's most likely a bug.

You basically have two options now:

1. Look for an alternative library to read PNG files.
2. Fix the transparency after you have read the PNG file. This only works if know that the image used the particular problematic format.

**Input and output for working PNG files**

Input image:

[image: Input image]

Ouptput Image:

[image: Output image]

Comment: It doesn't work. This way  I have an image with a black background only

Comment: Can you check the value of `image.getType()`? Does your source and your alpha channel really have an alpha channel that supports transparency?

Comment: After ImageIO.read(file); type is equal 12 (TYPE_BYTE_BINARY)

Comment: That might be the problem. Try to use `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` instead (in `new BufferedImage(...`);

Comment: I have changed to `BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);` but right now the resulting image does not contain the content from the previous one and has only transparent background

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't work, please try to rotate the following image http://download.decisionwanted.com/image2_cleared_1-2149x1417+1443+479.png  after rotation it contains white background instead of the transparent one - http://download.decisionwanted.com/image2_cleared_1-2149x1417+1443+479_rotated.png

Comment: Yes indeed, this image doesn't work. After analysis  in the debugger, it seems that ImageIO is at fault. The image uses an indexed color model with with just two colors: black and transparent. But after ImageIO has read it, the color model says it's opaque and none of the colors is transparent. That's incorrect. Further investigation is needed.

Comment: I've analyzed the issue in more detail. Please see my update.