# Rotate a buffered image with white background

Tags: java, bufferedimage, affinetransform

I want to rotate a `BufferedImage` by an angle in radians. I used the following code. `matrixImage` is a matrix of integers where foreground pixels have `1` as value while background pixels have `0` as value. The new `BufferedImage` is correctly rotated but the extra borders are black. The new image is bigger than the original one and the new parts are black. I want that all the background pixels of the new image are white. I tried the solution proposed at [Rotate BufferedImage and remove black bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48587644/rotate-bufferedimage-and-remove-black-bound), but I noticed that during the rotation the image changes.

```java
bufferedImage = matrix2BufferedImage(matrixImage);
AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.rotate(radians, bufferedImage.getWidth() / 2, bufferedImage.getHeight() / 2);
AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
bufferedImage = op.filter(bufferedImage, null);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate BufferedImage with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602703/rotate-bufferedimage-with-transparent-background)

Comment: Maybe this solution also will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925616/java-rotated-image-turns-all-black

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the following code for rotating

```
    private BufferedImage rotateImage(BufferedImage sourceImage, double angle) {
    AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
    transform.rotate(angle, sourceImage.getWidth() / 2, sourceImage.getHeight() / 2);
    AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(transform, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
    BufferedImage destImage = op.filter(sourceImage, null);

    Graphics2D g2d = destImage.createGraphics();

    g2d.drawRenderedImage(sourceImage, transform);

    g2d.dispose();
    return destImage;
}
```

Then, I binarised the buffered image with the following code

```
            int value=binarized.getRGB(x,y);
            if(value==0)
                value=-1;
            output[y][x] = ((0xFFFFFF & value) == 0xFFFFFF) ? (byte) 0 : 1;
```

Thanks for suggesting me the right post!